# Create with ViewModel that has two related entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have the properties for two entities in a ViewModel. The two entities are both related to one another, so for example, User and Posts. Each User can have multiple Posts, and Many Posts can belong to a single user (one-to-many).

The aim from my ViewModel is to allow the addition of a User and a Post on the same form. So my ViewModel looks something like this:

```
public class CreateVM
{
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(500), MinLength(50)]
    public string PostBody { get; set; }

    // etc with some other related properties
}
```

In my Controller on the Create Method I have something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateVM vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            User u = new User()
            {
                Username = vm.Username,
                // etc populate properties
            };

            Post p = new Post()
            {
                Body = vm.PostBody,
                // etc populating properties
            };

            p.User = u; // Assigning the new user to the post.

            XContext.Posts.Add(p);

            XContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

It all looks fine when I walk through it through the Debugger, but when I try to view the post, its User relationship is null!

I also tried

```
u.Posts.Add(p);
```

**UPDATE:**

My Post class code is as follows:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(500)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int Likes { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool isApproved { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

But that also did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the `Post` class code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that EF can not lazy load the `User` property because you haven't made it `virtual`.

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(500)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int Likes { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool isApproved { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

If you know beforehand that you are going to access the `User` property of the post you should eager load the `User` related to the post.

```
context.Posts.Include("User").Where(/* condition*/);
```

Comment: Thanks Eranga, I did not think that would be a problem, because I am not loading the User from the database (or am I?) because the User is being created at the same time that the Post is being created. I'll change it to Virtual and see what happens. Will post back.